# Troca de conteúdo entre páginas com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Eu preciso trocar um texto que está em um `<p>` de uma página x para um `<p>` de uma página y.

Como faz parte de uma apresentação bimestral (trabalho do curso) eu posso usar HTML, CSS3 e JavaScript.

Tem como fazer isso com alguma dessas tecnologias?

---

Desculpem minha falta de clareza com a pergunta, eu queria na verdade deixar a maior parte dos textos guardado em uma pagina que não seria carregada e iria servir apenas para tal, sendo acessado somente o texto em questão e exibido na pagina onde o usuario estivesse. Pesquisei um pouco sobre o assunto e só daria para fazer algo parecido com isso pelo php. Desculpem o trabalho e obrigado.

Comment: Podes explicar melhor como navegas entre páginas, se elas estão no mesmo domínio?

Comment: Você já fez alguma coisa? Mostre algum código.

Comment: Você quer levar um parágrafo de uma página HTML para outra página HTML? Para isso pode usar JavaScript, com ID diferentes no HTML.. Mas acredito que você esteja meio confuso ou explicou errado.

Comment: css3 é tecnologia pra estilizar páginas e não pra "carregar páginas". Acho que você precisa primeiro entender o que cada tecnologia faz.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é possivel com JavaScript. Tens duas alternativas:

- passar pelo URL
- guardar no *localStorage*

#### HTML de exemplo

Assumindo que o conteúdo que queres passar é este:

```
<p id="comentario">Hoje está um lindo dia!</p>
```

## Passando pelo URL

Podes inserir esse texto no URL que abre a próxima página. O formato será

> `http://teusite.com/pasta/subpasta?comentario=Hoje%20est%C3%A1%20um%20lindo%20dia!`

A parte do URL depois de `?` chama-se querystring e existe para passar dados entre páginas ou servidor.

Para inserires conteúdo no URL vais ter de mudar os links no HTML. A melhor maneira é com JavaScript usando `encodeURIComponent()` que é um método nativo para converter texto em formato aceite no URL.

Assim tens de procurar o link que queres que abra a próxima página e mudar:

Exemplo:

HTML

```
<a id="ancora" href="novapagina.html">Clique aqui</a>
```

JavaScript

```
var texto = document.getElementById('comentario').innerHTML;
var ancora = document.getElementById('ancora');
ancora.href = ancora.href + '?comentario=' + encodeURIComponent(texto );
```

Desta maneira, quando o link fôr clicado ele vai abrir a nova página com informação no URL/QueryString.

**E como ler isso na página nova?**

Para ler isso na página nova usa o `location.search` para te dar a querystring e depois retira o que te interessa:

JavaScript

```
var qs = location.search;
var textoDesformatado = qs.split('=');
var textoFinal = textoDesformatado[1] && decodeURIComponent(textoDesformatado);
// e depois, para inserir no novo <p id="comentario"></p> basta fazer
document.getElementById('comentario').innerHTML = textoFinal;
```

Nota:

também podes abrir uma página nova com JavaScript diretamente. Nesse caso seria algo como:

```
location.href = '/pasta/subpasta?comentario=' + encodeURIComponent(texto );
```

## Passando pelo localStorage

O local storage é a memória do browser e que fica ativa mesmo depois de desligar o computador. Ou seja o computador escreve num ficheiro interno do browser e vi buscar depois essa info.

Assim para escrevers no localStoragd basta fazer:

```
localStorage.comentario = document.getElementById('comentario').innerHTML;
```

e, na nova página, para ler o código basta fazer ao contrário:

```
document.getElementById('comentario').innerHTML = localStorage.comentario;
```

#### Nota:

Existem mais alternativas usando o servidor, mas não as incluo pois referiste apenas tecnologia do lado do cliente.

Comment: A resposta é boa, mas teria que fazer muias paginas a mais, e isso é algo que eu quero evitar. Por exemplo: O site que estou fazendo trata-se de mitologias, tem o site e uma imagem com cada deus, ao clicar na imagem ela aparece em um < aside > e o texto aparece ao lado da divindade. Eu seria obrigado a criar uma pagina pra cada deus se eu fizesse esse sistema. E serão 3 panteões diferentes e todos longos.

Answer (score 0):

tem como fazer isso usando diversas tecnologias e de diversas formas.
mas usando apenas html/css, aqui vai:

> pagina1.html

```
<h1>origem</h1>
<p id="p1">Primeiro</p>
<a href="pagina2.html" id="link">ir para a página 02</a>
<script>
    $('#link').attr( 'href', 'pagina2.html?' + $('p1').html() );
</script>
```

> pagina2.html

```
<h1>destino</h1>
<p id="p2"></p>
<script>
    var content = (location+"").split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
    $('#p2').html(content);
</script>
```

Comment: "Apenas HTML/CSS" Você usou apenas um arquivo HTML para fazer isso, mas você usou JavaScript e HTML. Não tem como fazer isso sem JavaScript. Mas como o autor não foi claro com a sua pergunta, pode ser que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Oi Fabio, bem vindo ao [pt.so]! No teu código não vejo ser necessário `.split('=')[1];`. Ou podes tirar essa parte ou então junta a chave na querystring: `?p=`. É bom lembrar o autor da pergunta (AP) que estás a usar jQuery, que tem de ser adicionado à página