# Como esconder um input field de uma outra página através do javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5

**Cenário**

Eu tenho duas página `.html`. Em uma das páginas eu tenho duas opções de marcar do tipo `radio` ambas possuem `id`, são elas XPTO e YPTO e. O que eu preciso fazer é, ao escolher XPTO e logo em seguida apertar no botão **cadastrar**, ele tem que desabilitar um campo na outra página.

No meu exemplo o campo se chama **Sobrenome**, para isso eu estava usando uma condição no *javascript* Se `document.getElementById("xpto").textContent` for este elemento, na outra página o campo **Sobrenome** desaparece.

Há alguma maneira de fazer isso, mesmo eu indo para uma outra página em seguida?

Meus códigos abaixo:

**PÁGINA 1: `test.html`**

```
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="xpto">XPTO</td>
                <td id="ypto">YPTO</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>        
    <br /><br />
    <button><a href="test2.html" onclick="disableSobrenome()">CADASTRAR</a></button>
</body>
```

**PÁGINA 2: `test2.html`**

```
<body>   


    <form>
        Nome:
        <input type="text" id="nome">
        Sobrenome:
        <input type="text" id="sobrenome">
    </form>

    <a href="test.html">VOLTAR</a>
</body>
```

**Script.js:**

```
function disableSobrenome() {

    if (document.getElementById("xpto").textContent)
    {
        document.getElementById("sobrenome").style.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89350/23400 talvez ajude...

Comment: @gustavox, obrigado, usando esse artigo que você citou, pude fazer um mix com a solução apresentada na página, +1.

Answer (score 2):

**test.html:**

```
<body>
    <form action="test2.html" method="get"> <!-- FORMULÁRIO SEMPRE UMA BOA OPÇÃO-->
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="opcao" value="xpto" type="radio"></td> <!-- EM RADIO SEMPRE COLOQUE O MESMO NOME E UM VALOR PARA EVITAR MARCAR DOIS -->
                    <td><input name="opcao" value="ypto" type="radio"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="xpto">XPTO</td>
                    <td id="ypto">YPTO</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>        
        <br/><br/>
        <button type="submit">CADASTRAR</button> <!-- BOTÃO TENDE A TER AÇÃO PARA FORMULÁRIO -->
    </form>
</body>
```

**test2.html:**

```
<body>   
    <form>
        <p id="nome">Nome:</p> <!-- COLOQUE IDENTIFICADORES EM TUDO -->
        <input type="text" id="nomeInput">
        <p id="sobrenome">Sobrenome:</p>
        <input type="text" id="sobrenomeInput">
    </form>

    <a href="test.html">VOLTAR</a>
</body>

<script>
    var url   = window.location.search.replace("?", ""); //pega url
    var itens = url.split("&"); //separa onde tem o parametro
    var valor = itens[0].slice(6); // 6 pois opcao= tem 6 caracteres
    if(valor == "xpto")
    {
        document.getElementById("sobrenomeInput").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("sobrenome").style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: obrigado por mais uma ajuda exemplar, o seu exemplo está perfeito, mas eu não posso usar <form> tem que ser <a>, mas usando seu exemplo posso tentar achar alguma solução alternativa, como por exemplo usar localStorage.

Comment: Da pra usar link (a) com form, so colocar ele com type submit

Comment: Rapaz, mais uma coisa que não sabia, rs. Mas mesmo assim não posso usar o <form>, tem que ser sem a tag <form>, somente posso usar <a>.

Comment: usando o seu código e mais o desse
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/89350/23400, pude resolver meu problema, obrigado, +1.